# How to sort an array of objects based on the numerical value of an object property?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array like this

```
var arr = [{ "name": "John", "age": "16" }, 
           { "name": "Charles", "age": "26" }, 
           { "name": "Charles", "age": "12" }, 
           { "name": "Charles", "age": "44" }, 
           { "name":"Charles", "age": "1" },
           { "name": "Charles", "age": "4"}]
```

The function i tried is

```
var sorted = yourArray.sort(function IHaveAName(a, b)
{ // non-anonymous as you ordered...
    return b.age < a.age ? 1 // if b should come earlier, push a to end
     : b.age > a.age ? -1 // if b should come later, push a to begin
     : 0;                   // a and b are equal
});
```

**result obtained**

```
[ { name: 'Charles', age: '1' },
{ name: 'Charles', age: '12' },
{ name: 'John', age: '16' },
{ name: 'Charles', age: '26' },
{ name: 'Charles', age: '4' },
{ name: 'Charles', age: '44' } ]
```

***In that charles having age 4 should come at top.***

where i am going wrong ?

Comment: So sort by alphabetical name first, then sort by ascending age?  Also, your ages are strings.

Comment: return +b.age < +a.age

Comment: Look at underscore.js, lots of functional syntactic sugar for js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ages are strings and are being sorted as such.

Run them through `parseInt` when you sort them if you want a numeric result.

```
var sorted = arr.sort(function IHaveAName(a, b)
{   var _a = parseInt(a.age, 10), _b = parseInt(b.age, 10);
    return _b < _a ? 1 // if b should come earlier, push a to end
     : _b > _a ? -1 // if b should come later, push a to begin
     : 0;                   // a and b are equal
});
```

Comment: `return a.age - b.age;`, the [`ToNumber` algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) is invoked implicitly by the [subtraction operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.2).